# In 1st law of Thermodynamics, $W=P_{ext}dV$ or $W=P_{int}dV$?

Tags: thermodynamics, work

[image]

Work done by the system of the piston = (Force applied on the system on the piston)×(displacement of the piston) = $F_{int}\cdot dS$=$P_{int}\cdot dV$

But, in my textbook, it is given $W=P_{ext}dV$

For a reversible process, this is okay, since $P_{int}=P_{ext}$ at all points, but what if it is not reversible? If $P_{int}\neq P_{ext}$, then which one is correct? Why?

Comment: Do you think that in an irreversible process, the force per unit area on the inside face of the piston is determined by the ideal gas law (or other real gas equation of state)?  If you do a force balance on a massless frictionless piston, what does Newton's 2nd law tell you?

Comment: @ChetMiller, umm.. I think if $P_{int}\neq P_{ext}$, and the piston is really massless, then it will gain a very large (undefined) acceleration...

Comment: That is not correct.  I will provide a correct answer later.

Comment: And you didn't answer my first question as to whether the ideal gas law determines the force per unit area on the inside face of the piston in an irreversible process.

Comment: @ChetMiller I don't think the gas law applies since system is not isotropic.. Anyways, thanks for the answer...

Comment: It applies if the process is reversible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As usual in Thermodynamics, any statement about interactions between a system and its surroundings requires careful identification of what the system is and what the surroundings are.

In the case of a fluid in a variable-volume container, the natural choice is to consider the fluid as the thermodynamic system and the outside world, including walls and piston, as surroundings.

In general, we have three forces to deal with:

1. the force acting on the piston from the outside world, ${\bf F}_{WP}$;
2. the force the inner wall of the piston acts on the fluid,  ${\bf F}_{P}$;
3. the force the fluid (the thermodynamic system) acts on the wall,  ${\bf F}_s$.

Forces $(2)$ and $(3)$ are an action-reaction pair and are always equal and opposite (${\bf F}_{P}=-{\bf F}_s$). Moreover, they are surface forces, and the modulus of force $(2)$ divided by the piston surface area ($A$) can be interpreted as the pressure exerted by the piston ($p_P=\frac{|{\bf F}_{P}|}{A}$). Modulus of force $(3)$ can be written as the internal pressure times the piston surface area only if the fluid is always at equilibrium (quasi-static processes). Therefore we have   $$p=\frac{|{\bf F}_{s}|}{A}=\frac{|{\bf F}_{P}|}{A}=p_P$$.

Even in the case of quasi-static processes, ${\bf F}_{WP}\neq {\bf F}_{P}$, if friction forces are present. In the case of a frictionless piston and a quasi-static transformation, we have also $p=p_P=p_{WP}=\frac{|{\bf F}_{WP}|}{A}$

Now, we can discuss the problem of the pressure appearing in the expression of work in the first principle.

We are interested in the work done by the system on the surroundings or by the surroundings on the system (depending on our tastes). These two quantities have the same magnitude since they depend on ${\bf F}_{s}$ or ${\bf F}_P=-{\bf F}_s$. If the internal pressure of the fluid is well-defined (quasi-static process), we arrive to
$$
W=p dV = p_P dV
$$
for the work done by the system on the surroundings (or the same expression with a minus sign in front of both pressures if we are interested in the work done by the surroundings on the system).

At this point, it should be clear the relation between the expression of work containing the *external* pressure ($p_{ext}dV$) and the one with the pressure of the fluid ($pdV$), depending on what we mean by $p_{ext}$.

- if we take $p_{ext}=p_{WP}$, the work $p_{ext}dV$ does not coincide in general with the work varying the internal energy of the fluid system. It does only in the case of a frictionless piston. The reason is that part of the external work goes into dissipative processes located at the piston-wall interface, which is not part of the thermodynamic system of interest (the fluid).
- if we take $p_{ext}=p_{P}$ the work $p_{ext}dV$ is the correct one to be used in connection with the first principle, but it can be written as $pdV$ only in the case of a quasi-static process.

Comment: `Forces (2) and (3) are an action-reaction pair and are always equal and opposite` then shouldn't $|p_{P}|=|p|$ always hold, even for non quasi-static process? In that case shouldn't $W=pdV$ be the correct expression even for non quasi-static process?  Can you please clarify this `but it can be written as pdV only in the case of a quasi-static process.`

Comment: `If the internal pressure of the fluid is well-defined (quasi-static process)`  -- Also, do you mean that for a frictionless, massless piston; $p_P$ and $p_int$ are defined only for quasi-static process?  I can think of the logic that, in case of a non quasi-static process, $F_WP=0$ and $F_s\neq 0$ would provide an undefined acdeleration of the piston?

Comment: @AsmitKarmakar forces are always well-defined. What may not be equally well-defined is a uniform pressure over the whole boundary of the fluid. If the fluid is not at equilibrium, there is the guarantee that pressure is uniform everywhere in the fluid.

Answer (score 2):

P external

Think about free expansion in vacuum
there is no work in vacuum

For a free expansion into a vacuum, a gas does no work because there is no resistance on the gas as P=0.

Answer (score 1):

In an irreversible process (non-quasi-static), the ideal gas law (or other real gas equation of state) is not valid, and does not determine the force per unit area on the inside face of the piston.  The ideal gas law (or other equation of state) is only valid at thermodynamic equilibrium (or in a reversible process, which is comprised of a continuous sequence of thermodynamic equilibrium states).  When you study fluid dynamics, you will learn that, in an irreversible process, there are viscous stresses present in the gas that contribute to the compressive force per unit area at the inside piston face. So you can't use the ideal gas law to get the work done by the gas on the piston.

If you apply Newton's 2nd law correctly to a massless, frictionless piston, you must conclude that the internal force per unit area exerted by the gas on the inside face of the piston (which is typically called $P_{Int}$, but which is not determined by the ideal gas law for an irreversible process) must be equal at all times to the external force per unit area $P_{ext}$ exerted on the outside face of the piston, irrespective of the rate of acceleration of the piston (which is not infinite, because the gas itself has mass), and irrespective of whether the process is reversible or irreversible.

So, to summarize, $P_{Int}=P_{ext}$ for both reversible and irreversible processes, but only in the case of a reversible process are they determined by the ideal gas law.  In the case of an irreversible process, we must specify them by imposing some constraint externally to the system, such as forcing $P_{ext}$ to be constant manually.

Answer (score 1):

- It is **always** $dW = - P_\text{ext} dV$.
- **If** the process is quasistatic, then by definition $P_\text{ext}=P_\text{int}$ and in this special case

$$ dW = dW_\text{rev} = - P_\text{int} dV$$

Answer (score 0):

Both are correct. When work done upon the system, $P_E$. When work done by the system, $P_I$.

In case of $P_E$, when pressure exerted on piston by external mechanical means, it compress the gas inside of chamber which we considered as system. After compressing $dV$, the external pressure amounts to internal pressure. So external pressure done only that amount of work when it equals to internal pressure. Similarly for work done by the system and product of pressure and change in volume equals to work done,

$W=P_IdV=-P_EdV\tag*{}$

Negative sign is to show that volume decreases, which comes naturally in calculation.